# addClass on click, then recount total classes

Tags: jquery, class, size, alert, slice

I have elements with inside the slideimg div which I add a Class to.

I want to give the element without a class the class `slideright` on click, then afterwards recount the elements with the class `slideright`.

```
<div id="slideimg">
<img src="images/portfolio/1.jpg" alt="image1" />
<img src="images/portfolio/2.jpg" alt="image2" />
<img src="images/portfolio/3.jpg" alt="image3" />
<img src="images/portfolio/4.jpg" alt="image4" />
</div>
```

```js
var slideimg = $('#slideimg');
//add classes to images
slideimg.children().eq(0).addClass('slidecontent');
slideimg.children().slice(1, 4).addClass('slideright');
                
var slideright = $('.slideright');
var slidecontent = $('.slidecontent');
var totalrightimg = slideright.size();

slidecontent.click(function(){
$(this).addClass('slideright').removeClass('slidecontent');
totalrightimg = slideright.size();
alert(totalrightimg);
});
```

Comment: Your code works in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VZvur/. Are your `div` elements being appended dynamically?

Comment: not appended, there are 4 items total, i used the slice function to get the last 3 and add the right class to them.
$('body').children('div').slice(1,3).addClass('right')

Comment: Please post your actual code then, since the code you have posted does not reproduce the problem.

Comment: i think your issue is `you are not clicking the div 1 at first to add the class` to it. Thus `.size()` of the `.right is 3`.

Comment: @Jai It is almost certain that is dummy HTML, since the alert wouldn't occur at all if the OP weren't able to click the element.

Comment: i edited my code to my current one, i thought that i would be able to recreate the same problem, turns out that my problem is somewhere else..

Answer (score 0):

I just changed html as:

```
<div>here</div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Checkout this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/ZJSqY/
Your code works fine...
Tell me how can you click on empty div container?

Comment: You didn't change the HTML at all. I don't understand why people are rushing to post pointless answers without trying to identify the problem.

Comment: existing provided code works well. what is the use of blank divs.

Comment: blank divs was because i didnt add the css, but im afraid that i misunderstood where my problem was coming from, i edited my post with the real problem..